# Listen to sub-sub views in Backbone Marionette

Tags: marionette

I have a collection view, and each item view is a composite view, which also has a item view. I want to listen to the events from this last (sub-sub) item view.

```
View.Block = Marionette.Layout.extend({
    triggers: {
        'click .content': 'block:click'
    }
});

View.Category = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemView: View.Block
});

View.Categories = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: View.Category
});
```

In my controller I only have a reference to View.Categories:

```
var categories_view = new View.Categories({
    collection: categories
});
```

Is it possible to listen to click events from `View.Block` using Marionette's built-in view events? I tried `categories_view.on('itemview:block:click')` but that won't work as View.Block isn't an item view of `View.Categories`, but of `View.Category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a module- or application-level event aggregator to achieve your objective:

```
events: {
  "click .something": "triggerEvent"
},

triggerEvent: function(e){
  myApp.trigger("something:clicked", e);
}
```

(`myApp` is the instance of your Marionette application.)

Then listen for that event:

```
myApp.on("something:clicked", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("something was clicked");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the way I currently made it work. I was just hoping/wondering for a solution using Marionette's view events.

Comment: The thing is, view events only get sent to the immediate parent. Since the place you want to listen form is more removed, you'll need to use an event aggregator.

Comment: `myApp,trigger` is that a typo..?

Comment: Yes, sorry. `trigger` is a method available on the app instance. The code is now fixed.